# react-router v6 how to match the url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have another piece of code and want to know the principle of `react-router` url matching. For example, the following code does not render the `Layout` component under `"/login"`, which is the effect I want, but I want to know *why*. Can someone explain?

```
<Router>
  <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path='/*'
        // Layout render another routes but no /login path
        element={<Layout /> }
      />
      <Route 
        path='/login'
        element={<LoginPage />}
      />
    </Routes>
  </Suspense>
</Router>
```

Layout code

```js
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>main page xxxx</div>
      <div>
        <Routes>
          <Route
            path='/demo1'
            element={<Demo1 /> }
          />
          <Route
            path='/demo2'
            element={<Demo2 /> }
          />
        </Routes>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

When path is `"/login"`, will the `Layout` component render something? How does the `react-router@6` match url?

Comment: @YuvarajM If OP removes the wildcard matcher from the route then the descendent routes `Layout` is rendering can't be matched and render out their content. The `"*"` is necessary, `path="/*"` isn't wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic gist is that `react-router` works by [conditionally rendering](https://react.dev/learn/conditional-rendering) selected UI based on matching the current URL path to a set of configured routes.

Route matching in `react-router@6` uses a [Path Ranking System](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#ranking-routes) to compute a score, or rank, for all route paths within a given `Routes` component . The `Routes` component takes the current URL path and [matches](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/start/concepts#matching) it to the highest ranked route, by path, that it is managing. Generally speaking, the *more* specific the route path is, the higher the rank. The ranking mostly serves to break ties between competing matches since ultimately only 1 can be matched and rendered.

Think of the `Routes` component as a `switch` statement where the condition is the path match to the current URL path. In fact, the `Routes` component replaced the older v5 `Switch` component.

For the routes configuration:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/*" element={<Layout /> } />
  <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
</Routes>
```

When the URL is `"domain/login"`, the best match is obviously the `"/login"` route. This route will be matched and the `LoginPage` will be rendered. The `Layout` component is not rendered at all, nor is it even mounted in the ReactTree.

On the other hand, when the URL is anything but `"domain/login"`, something like `"domain/foo"`, then `"/login"` cannot be matched and the next highest ranked route, `"/*"` is the best match and the `Layout` component is rendered. `LoginPage` is now not rendered or mounted at all.

Answer (score 0):

in react-router, you can not use it like that. In the first block you already declare  and  that's why you can not push another  in the layout. The solution will be like that you can try this:

```
<Router>
  <Suspense fallback={<PageLoading />}>
    <Routes>
      <Route
        path='/'
       // Layout renders another routes but no /login path
        element={<Layout /> }
      />
      <Route 
        path='/login'
        element={<LoginPage />}
      />
      <Route
        path='/demo1'
        element={<Demo1 /> }
      />
      <Route
        path='/demo2'
        element={<Demo2 /> }
      />
    </Routes>
  </Suspense>
</Router>
```

In layout, you can try like this

```
const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>main page xxxx</div>
      <div>
          <Link
            to='/demo1'
          />
          <Link
            to='/demo2'
          />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you saying is the issue? OP doesn't have any problem rendering any of their routes and isn't asking for help with that.